# Check if function exist in bat

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Is there any way for checking if Function exist Then do Sth?

For example :

```
:Work
:: Code
exit /b
```

Comment: Unless your code modifies itself, you should ***know*** which functions (better call it labels or subroutines) do exist. `findstr /bic:":Work" %~f0 ||(Echo no label :Work)&&(do sth)`

Comment: There are use cases were this is necessary. I'm creating a program that stores scripts in a seperate file and calls them. By checking if the label exists it gets some error handling.

Comment: @user6811411 the only issue with your command is that if say, `:workisdone` exists, it will still trigger as a find.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to find all lines beginning with a colon inside a batch file.

If so, you need something like this: `type mybatch.bat | findStr /I /R "^:.*$"`

To check for one specific function name the part behind the /R should be `"^:MyFunctionName\>"`.

You can invoke this within a `for` statement and send the output to `nul` to not show it inside the console window.
If you want to check for possible multiple occurances you need to add "delayed expansion" of the variables (for `count` in the example below).

A full example would be like this:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set cmd=type mybatch.bat ^| findStr /I /R "^:MyFunctionName\>"

for /f "usebackq" %%f in (`%cmd% ^> nul`) do (
  echo ...do something...
  echo function name found: %%f
  set /a count = !count! + 1
  if !count! == 2 (
    echo function exists more than once^^!
  ) 
)
```

The `cmd` variable increases readability and prevents some conflicts with escaping/expanding the wildcard symbols of the RegEx, like asterisk/* (unlimited repetitions) and caret/^ (beginning of line). The dollar/$ denotes end of line and `\>` end of a word.

Comment: I'm afraid, you misunderstood. OP needs to check if a certain label exists. (Easy, when you adapt your REGEX a bit)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Enhanced my answer.

Comment: I would `findstr /bir ":MyFunctionName\>"` to avoid false positives with `:MyFunctioNameTwo`. And some mad people (like me) like to put a comment after the label. And technically, a label doesn't have to be at the beginning of a line, there may be spaces or tabs or even some other characters before (although you rarely see that). Even `= ; , :MyFunctionName some comment` is a technically valid label (but even I am not mad enough to really do this).

Comment: line continuation is possible using `^`

Comment: what makes this even worse is that `::` is a common substitute of `REM` or `%= COMMENT =%`

Comment: Well, even if these are technically valid labels (and it is borderline grotesque to think about code that really uses it), OP did not mention any of such special cases... and I hope they are not relevant. Of course the RegEx could be enhanced to cover such cases as well. This is another exercise then, I believe :)  -- Really Wow :D Using parameters behind a label as possibility for comments... cool. OR Variables as comments enclosed by %=... excellent :'D I did know about :: but learned some time that it is really a degenerate label which only works as a comment due to some side effects.

Comment: I fully agree. But  `\>` ("End of Word") instead `$` ("End of Line") would enhance it enough to avoid false positives and comments (let's not care of the other crazy coding possibilities I mentioned earlier)